# Transparent point is not transparent at some degrees in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

[demo link](https://codepen.io/Hypnosss/pen/mdedYxE)

```
//vertexShader
attribute float percent;
varying float vPercent;
void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
    vPercent = percent;
}

//fragmentShader
varying float vPercent;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3(0.0), vPercent );
}
```

```
let points = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    points.push(new THREE.Vector3(i / 1000, 1, 0));
}

let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
let percents = new Float32Array(1000);        
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {        
    percents[i] = i / 1000;  
}
geometry.addAttribute('percent', new THREE.BufferAttribute(percents, 1));

let line = new THREE.Points(geometry, 
    new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: shader_content["vertexShader"],
        fragmentShader: shader_content["fragmentShader"],
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        transparent: true
    })
);
scene.add(line);
```

Rotate the scene, points are all black at some degrees. THREE.js 109.
Is it a bug or it is just what it supposed to be?

Screenshots may explain better.

[all black picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suzL2.png)

[normal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHxKN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a depth sorting issue that can be avoid by setting `depthWrite` of your shader material to `false`. The points do not flicker anymore and you always see the expected result (which actually corresponds to your black picture).

Comment: Thanks for reply.Is there any possible ways like refreshing depthBuffer while rotating to make things show always like the normal picture?

Comment: The picture is not "normal". It's actually wrong since the blending is not performed correctly.